# IW31 searching for a user exit or enh. point to get gsber

Tags: hook, abap, sap-erp

I am working with transaction `IW31`, the task is to rewrite the field of `gsber` with another value during the save process (when I clicked the save button this function should be activated at this time).

I had seen all the relevant user exit and enhancement point corresponding to transaction `iw31` but no success. I couldn't find any point where I can get the whole `CAUFVD` structure (it contains the field `gsber`).

I would need a user point where I can import this structure, not only export.

Could anybody help me solving this task? Or do I need to create an implicit point because the lack of User-Exit?

Thank you in advance,
Gabor

Answer (score 1):

Which SAP Release do you use?

Have you checked the Include `LCOIHF2V`? There you will find the Enhancement Point `FCODE_BU2_01` in which you have full access to structure `CAUFVD`.

```
ENHANCEMENT-POINT FCODE_BU2_01 SPOTS ES_SAPLCOIH STATIC.
```

In addition you have of course always the possibility to add an implicit enhancement (as you suggested) at the end of this form routine.

Hope this helps!